# Grouping unaligned blocks into containers using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I created a block diagram in which I want to group blocks into two different labeled containers, as shown in the image below.

[image]

I can group the four blocks in the upper-left corner using something like: `\node (client) [draw, fit= (disp) (dec) (head) (track)]  {};` as described in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291591/grouping-two-blocks-in-a-container-horizontally-within-a-diagram) answer but I couldn't figure out a straightforward way to group blocks that are not completely aligned with each other.

Here is a MWE (without the desired grouping and labeling):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, fit, calc, shapes}  
\tikzset{  
    line/.style={-latex},   
    N/.style={draw, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, font=\sffamily},  
    arr/.style = {draw, -{Triangle}}, 
    arr2/.style = {draw, thick, -{Triangle}},
}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3mm and 15mm]
\node (net) [N,rounded corners=2mm, minimum size=28mm] {Network}; 
\node (track) [N, above left=of net.south west]  {Tracking}; 
\node (head) [N, left=of track] {Head movement};  
\node (dec) [N, below left=of net.north west]  {Video decoder}; 
\node (disp) [N, left=of dec]  {Display}; 
\node (render) [N, above right=of net.south east] {Renderer};
\node (enc) [N, below right=of net.north east] {Video encoder};
%\node (client) [draw, fit= (disp) (dec) (head) (track)]  {};
\coordinate[right=of render] (aux);
\draw[arr]  
(head) edge node[above] {$x_k$} (track) 
(track) edge node[above] {$z_k$} (track -| net.west) 
(dec -| net.west) edge (dec)
(dec) edge (disp)
(enc)  edge  (enc -| net.east)
(render) -- (aux) |- (enc);
\node (update) [N, below of=net, yshift=-3.5cm]  {Measurement update};
\node (model) [N, label=$\mathrm{H_k}$, left=of update] {Measurement model};
\node (estimate) [N, label=$\mathrm{F_k}$, left=of model] {State \\ estimation $\mathrm{F_k}$};
\node (pred) [N, right=of update, xshift=0.3cm] {Prediction};
\node (lat) [text centered, below=of pred, yshift=-0.7cm]  {$t_{\mathrm{LAT}}$};
\node (updateout) [coordinate, node distance=8mm, right=of update]  {};
\node (delay) at ($(model)+(0,-1.5)$) [N]  {Delay};
\draw[arr] 
(model) edge node[above] {$\hat{z}_{k}$} (update)
(estimate) edge node[above] {$\hat{x}_{k}^-$} (model)
(net.south) edge  node [right,pos=0.5] {$z_k$} (update.north)
(update) edge node[above] {$\hat{x}_{k}^+$} (pred)
(updateout) |- node [above,pos=0.8] {} (delay)
(delay) -| node [above,pos=0.25] {$\hat{x}_{k-1}$} (estimate)
(lat.north) edge (pred.south)
(pred.north) -- node [right,pos=0.5] {$\hat{x}_{k+N}$} (render.south);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automated option with `fit` will not serve to obtain shapes with the sum of these, what you will get is a node that includes all located in a geometric center between them, but what the example requires exceeds the possibilities of fit, at least those that I know, for example the offset of the sides is not symmetrical, it must include the spaces occupied even by the paths of the arrows, so you only have to do it manually, but for this it has the `calc` library, which will allow you to find relative points to other existing ones `($(node_name.node_specific_point)+(x_shift,y_shift)$)`, moving or finding barycentric points in a line `($(node_A)!K!(node_B)$)`.

ADDENDUM: You should also note that the `(render)` and `(pred)` nodes will not be vertically aligned, so the arrow that joins them will not be vertical, to fix that you must find a projected orthogonal point `(pred.south|-render.south)`.

RESULT: Added some modifications hoping they are not bad style, with opacity controls for some collateral damage.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta, fit, calc, shapes}  
\tikzset{  
    line/.style={-latex},   
    N/.style={draw, thick, text width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, font=\sffamily},  
    arr/.style = {draw, -{Triangle}}, 
    arr2/.style = {draw, thick, -{Triangle}},
}  
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3mm and 15mm]
    \node (net) [N,rounded corners=2mm, minimum size=28mm] {Network}; 
    \node (track) [N, above left=of net.south west]  {Tracking}; 
    \node (head) [N, left=of track] {Head movement};  
    \node (dec) [N, below left=of net.north west]  {Video decoder}; 
    \node (disp) [N, left=of dec]  {Display}; 
    \node (render) [N, above right=of net.south east] {Renderer};
    \node (enc) [N, below right=of net.north east] {Video encoder};
    \coordinate[right=of render] (aux);
    \draw[arr]  
    (head) edge node[above] {$x_k$} (track) 
    (track) edge node[above] {$z_k$} (track -| net.west) 
    (dec -| net.west) edge (dec)
    (dec) edge (disp)
    (enc)  edge  (enc -| net.east)
    (render) -- (aux) |- (enc);
    \node (update) [N, below of=net, yshift=-3.5cm]  {Measurement update};
    \node (model) [N, label=$\mathrm{H_k}$, left=of update] {Measurement model};
    \node (estimate) [N, label=$\mathrm{F_k}$, left=of model] {State \\ estimation $\mathrm{F_k}$};
    \node (pred) [N, right=of update, xshift=0.3cm] {Prediction};
    \node (lat) [text centered, below=of pred, yshift=-0.7cm]  {$t_{\mathrm{LAT}}$};
    \node (updateout) [coordinate, node distance=8mm, right=of update]  {};
    \node (delay) at ($(model)+(0,-1.5)$) [N]  {Delay};
    \draw[arr] 
    (model) edge node[above] {$\hat{z}_{k}$} (update)
    (estimate) edge node[above] {$\hat{x}_{k}^-$} (model)
    (net.south) edge  node [right,pos=0.5] {$z_k$} (update.north)
    (update) edge node[above] {$\hat{x}_{k}^+$} (pred)
    (updateout) |- node [above,pos=0.8] {} (delay)
    (delay) -| node [above,pos=0.25] {$\hat{x}_{k-1}$} (estimate)
    (lat.north) edge (pred.south)
    (pred.north) -- node [right,pos=0.5] {$\hat{x}_{k+N}$} (pred.south|-render.south); % Give a point straight from pred.south in Renderer node.
    %Structure using a single \draw instruction...
    \draw[blue!50!cyan,dashed,fill,fill opacity=0.05,text opacity=1]%Get points using calc lib
    ($(disp.north west)+(-4pt,+5pt)$)
        rectangle ($(track.south east)+(15pt,-3pt)$)
    ($(head)!0.5!(track)$)++(0,-25pt)
        node[N,blue!50!cyan,draw=none]{Client}
    ($(estimate.north west)+(-5pt,+15pt)$) coordinate (temp1)
        -| ($(enc.north west)+(-10pt,+5pt)$) coordinate (temp2)
        -| ($(pred.south east)+(+50pt,-50pt)$)
        -| cycle
    ($(temp1)!0.5!(temp1-|temp2)$)++(0,6pt)
        node[N,blue!50!cyan,draw=none]{Server};
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great tip on the vertical alignment.